# Reference to the current tab in storyboard UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I added the following code in my AppDelegate application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to make reference to the UITabBarController I've created in storyboard (like the Tabbed Application template). Then I want self.currentController reprecent the *current* tab (ViewController). I can make it reprecent one of the tabs like this and get name of that ViewController for self.currentController in Log:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
self.currentController = [[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

But how to make it reprecent the *currently dislplayed* tab?

I've tried:

```
self.currentController = tabController.selectedViewController
```

I get warning: Incompatible pointer assigning to UIViewController<BannerViewContainer> from UIViewController. 
If I NSLog self.currentController now it says (null).

I've also tried different combinations of code from the [UITabBarController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I can't make it work. What's the right code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `tabController.selectedViewController`

Comment: If I write self.currentController = tabController.selectedViewController I get warning: Incompatible pointer assigning to UIViewController<SubViewContainer> from UIViewController. If I NSLog self.currentController it's (null).

Comment: Your controller object is called SubViewContainer I take it? You may need to cast the view controller `self.currentController = (SubViewContainer *)tabController.selectedViewController;`